# Exiled Players/Betrayer Dead of Winter TLN

Tags: dead-of-winter

If you have a player that is voted into exile, must that player immediately reveal to the rest of the group whether they are actually the betrayer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

When the players vote in favor of exiling a player, the exiled player must immediately draw 1 exiled secret objective card. This text of that card follows the following template:

> - If you are not the betrayer: Reveal your secret objective to all players and remove it from the game. Your new secret objective is now the following: [...]
> - If you are the betrayer: The 1st goal on your secret objective has changed to the following: [...]

So you must implicitly reveal that you are the betrayer by keeping your original secret objective card.

[image: Example exiled secret objective cards]

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the info. It seems silly that I didn't know that, based on the fact that it is printed on the cards. We just bought last night and my boyfriend and I played a game to get the hang of it to help explain to our friends. Since there were only 2 of us we played co-op and we didn't need/want to read the betrayer or exiled objectives so that when we do play with a larger group we could be just as surprised by the objectives as our friends and not have the upper hand of having read all the cards beforehand.

Comment: @Holly Also note that "If at any time there are 2 exiled players and neither had a
betrayal secret objective, morale immediately drops to 0. "